# Is there for imageView In variable

Tags: window

How can I solve this problem on Android studio that the imageView refuse to insert in findViewById(R.id.imageview) it is given me that I most looked up

````
type here
```image = findViewById(R.id.imageView)


Pls help me[text]


How can I looked up the image in R.id how can put without error
````